# When does $k$-th central moment relate to $k$-th power of expectation?

Tags: probability, expected-value, exponential-distribution

Given a bounded random variable $X$. When exactly is the $k$-th central moment $ E (X-\mu)^k $ upper bounded by the $k$-th power of the expectation $ \mu^k$? This seems to be the case for bounded, exponentially distributed random variables. Is there a more general condition or even a equivalent characterisation when that holds?

Comment: How do you define $E^k(X-\mu)$?  "The k-th power of the first central moment" is zero by definition.

Comment: Thanks, I meant the expectation!

Comment: What do you mean by "related"? We need to be clear what you expect the relationship to look like

Comment: I mean upper bounded, will edit that!

Comment: Some distributions don't even have higher moments.

Comment: @user619894 yes sure, I am asking for cases where this is achievable.

Comment: If you take such a distribution and truncate, you can get high moments that are as large as you want. So not bounded by the mean.

Comment: I am totally aware that there are such cases, taking the Cauchy distribution, then not even the mean exists. I am interested in cases, where this works, not in counterexamples